# Set Datepicker Field Format

Tags: html, angular, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

### Date returned by bank is not shown on screen.

I need to set my date field to receive a `Timestamp` object instead of a `Date` object that it receives by default.

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

In my application, I use the **Cloud Firestore** database and the date returned is a `Timestamp` object.

How do I make my date field be prepared to receive an object of type `Timestamp`?

Below is what I have in my code.

**component.html:**

```
        <mat-form-field class="mr-sm-24" fxFlex>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" formControlName="startDate" placeholder="Data de ínicio">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field fxFlex>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dueDatePicker" formControlName="dueDate" placeholder="Data término">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dueDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #dueDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

I am sending a Date object created by [mat-datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) to the database, but upon receiving the records from **Cloud Firestore** it returns me a `Timestamp` object and my field waits for a `Date` object and then does not show the date on the screen.

I need a way to get my [mat-datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) field to receive a `Timestamp` object returned by **Cloud Firestore**.